# How to compare array of dates with greater than current date

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, nsdate

How to compare array of 'date' strings with greater than  and less than current `date` in swift.
this is the array i am getting from server.

```
"leave_dates": [
        "03-09-2017",
        "04-09-2017",
        "05-09-2017",
        "04-09-2017",
        "01-09-2017",
        "07-09-2017",
        "09-09-2017",
        "10-09-2017",
        "12-09-2017",
        "13-09-2017",
        "15-09-2017",
        "16-09-2017",
        "23-09-2017"
    ],
```

Comment: That is not an array of dates. That is an array of strings.

Comment: `(NS)DateFormatter` in order to do `(NS)String` <-> `(NS)Date`.

Comment: Where is your tried code !!!

Comment: yeah array of strings.. it was typo mistake @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Resolved my issue by using stack overflow suggestions. and i am posting my answer it may helpful for others.

```
extension Date {
    var startOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: sunday)
    }

    var endOfWeek: Date? {
        let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        guard let sunday = gregorian.date(from: gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self)) else { return nil }
        return gregorian.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: sunday)
    }
    func generateDatesArrayBetweenTwoDates(startDate: Date , endDate:Date) ->[Date]
    {
        var datesArray: [Date] =  [Date]()
        var startDate = startDate
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let fmt = DateFormatter()
        fmt.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"
        while startDate <= endDate {
            datesArray.append(startDate)
            startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
        }
        return datesArray
    }
}
```

i am using that function like this.

```
func dateList() {
        let startWeek = Date().startOfWeek
        let endWeek = Date().endOfWeek
        datesBetweenArray = Date().generateDatesArrayBetweenTwoDates(startDate: startWeek! , endDate: endWeek!) as NSArray
        print(datesBetweenArray)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to convert your `string date` into a `Date` object, you do this by using the `DateFormatter`. Then you can use a `filter` to check if the date is greater than today:

```
let dates =  ["03-09-2017", "04-09-2017", "05-09-2017", "04-09-2017", "01-09-2017", "07-09-2017", "09-09-2017", "10-09-2017", "12-09-2017", "13-09-2017", "15-09-2017", "16-09-2017", "23-09-2017"]

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let greaterThanToday = dates.filter({ dateFormatter.date(from: $0)! > Date() })
print(greaterThanToday) // ["23-09-2017"]
```

Comment: this is the err0r i am getting whhile usong you code--- Cannot convert value of type '(String) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'NSPredicate'

Comment: @kishan this error no make sense. how you tried so far

Comment: i am assigning dates array to my json array(which i am getting from server Array)

Answer (score 0):

use `Dateformtter` class to convert it to date and then compare with the todays date. You can wrap the code in CustomDateFormatter and use static function to compare dates and return the bool.

```
class CustomDateFormatter {

    // MARK: - Properties
    private static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        return formatter
    }

    // MARK: - Public
    static func date(from string: String) -> Date? {
        return dateFormatter.date(from: string)
    }

    static func campare(_ string: String, with date: Date = Date()) -> Bool {
        guard let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: string) else {
            return false
        }
        return newDate > date
    }
}
```

now you can use it like

```
    let leave_dates = ["03-09-2017", "04-09-2017", "05-09-2017", "04-09-2017", "01-09-2017", "07-09-2017", "09-09-2017", "10-09-2017", "12-09-2017", "13-09-2017", "15-09-2017", "16-09-2017", "23-09-2017"]
    let today = Date()
    let greaterThanToday = leave_dates.filter { (date) -> Bool in
        return CustomDateFormatter.campare(date, with: today)
    }
    print(greaterThanToday)
```